# Magmi configurable \ simple link?

Tags: magento, hyperlink, product, configurable, magmi

Can anyone show me how to link the simple product to the configurable?  I've tried to directly export and import using magmi but it becomes unlinked after imported.  I can not find any info on it in here.  there are post relating to it, but none of them really explains how.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: before importing, you have to make sure that the attribute that varies in the simple product exists and is properly configured. Please make sure of this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an (partial) example - usual required fields still required too:

```
sku     type         size   configurable_attributes name
RT44508 simple       8                              Womens Dress
RT44510 simple       10                             Womens Dress
RT445   configurable        size                    Womens Dress
```

- So you have the simple items first, then the 'parent' configurable one.
- The sku of the simple items begins with the sku of the conifugurable.
- The attribute that is being used to configure them is in the `configurable_attributes` column
- That attributes value for simple items is in a column with that attributes code as it's name.

Does that help?

The documentation mentioned in another answer is good too.

Comment: What if i need SKU Start with different for simple

Comment: The second option for the plugin caters for that case @Bhupendra - just make sure your simples are before their configurables in the data set